# Google area chart empty page with data from JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, google-visualization

I am working on a KPI dashboard, my database contains hot water (*hwater*) usage per month(*adate*), comparing this year with last year as an area chart.

However when I run this report my webpage is blank. I have tried setting google.visualization.arrayToDataTable to .DataTable while declaring the column names and also tried with server side AJAX with no success.

Area_Chart.php

```
<?php
require_once  ("connect.php");

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$query = $handler->query("
    SELECT MONTH(adate) as month,
    MAX(case when YEAR(adate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1 THEN  hwater ELSE 0 END) as 'Last_Year',
    MAX(case when YEAR(adate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) THEN hwater ELSE 0 END) as 'This_Year'
    FROM utlt
    WHERE YEAR(adate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1 OR year(adate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
    GROUP BY MONTH(adate)
    ORDER BY MONTH(adate)");

$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$json=json_encode($results);

//echo $json;
?>    

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          [ {label: 'Year', id: 'month'},
            {label: 'Last_Year', id: 'Last_Year', type: 'number'},
            {label: 'This_Year', id: 'This_Year', type: 'number'}],
          <?=$json?>      
        ], false);


        var options = {
          isStacked: 'absolute',
          title: 'Hot Water Useage',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0}

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      } 


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output of echo $json:

```
[["1","1.671","21.269"],["2","3.810","22.017"],["3","5.554","24.045"],["4","6.930","25.036"],["5","8.845","27.116"],["6","11.793","28.058"],["7","13.244","28.996"],["8","14.471","30.342"],["9","16.260","30.977"],["10","17.199","31.923"],["11","18.494","33.155"],["12","19.563","33.797"]]
```

I notice above that *hwater* from *utlt* are rapped in **""**, does this mean its a string? The field type is actually a decimal (6,3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*hwater* from *utlt* being wrapped in "" is definitely a problem,
since the column type is `'number'`

try using `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` to encode the json

`$json=json_encode($results, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

**EDIT**

think i found the problem here...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  [ {label: 'Year', id: 'month'},
    {label: 'Last_Year', id: 'Last_Year', type: 'number'},
    {label: 'This_Year', id: 'This_Year', type: 'number'}],
  <?=$json?>  // <-- problem    
], false);
```

the problem is the outer array wrapping the row arrays
`//--> [[1,1.671,21.269]...`

given where `<?=$json?>` is placed, the rows shouldn't be wrapped in array

this can easily be corrected by using the `addRows` method to load the json

remove json from `arrayToDataTable`

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  [ {label: 'Year', id: 'month', type: 'number'},
    {label: 'Last_Year', id: 'Last_Year', type: 'number'},
    {label: 'This_Year', id: 'This_Year', type: 'number'}],
]);
```

then add another statement for the `addRows` method, which needs the outer array

```
data.addRows(
  <?=$json?>
);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [ {label: 'Year', id: 'month', type: 'number'},
      {label: 'Last_Year', id: 'Last_Year', type: 'number'},
      {label: 'This_Year', id: 'This_Year', type: 'number'}],
  ]);

  data.addRows(
    [[1,1.671,21.269],[2,3.810,22.017],[3,5.554,24.045],[4,6.930,25.036],[5,8.845,27.116],[6,11.793,28.058],[7,13.244,28.996],[8,14.471,30.342],[9,16.260,30.977],[10,17.199,31.923],[11,18.494,33.155],[12,19.563,33.797]]
  );

  var options = {
    isStacked: 'absolute',
    title: 'Hot Water Useage',
    hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
    vAxis: {minValue: 0}

  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for for your input and checking up.

I Added what you said, this resulted in the array looking like so; `[[1,1.671,21.269],[2,3.81,22.017],[3,5.554,24.045],[4,6.93,25.036],[5,8.845,27.116],[6,11.793,28.058],[7,13.244,28.996],[8,14.471,30.342],[9,16.26,30.977],[10,17.199,31.923],[11,18.494,33.155],[12,19.563,33.797]]`

When I sue this in my Area_Chart.php I get a blank page still.

Comment: maybe try changing the first column to --> `{label: 'Year', id: 'month', type: 'number'}`

Comment: Oh yes, just as I posted I saw that it was missing Type, I added it but unfortunately it didn't seem to change anything either.

Comment: If I comment out the label parameters `/*[ {label: 'Year',       id: 'month',      type: 'number'},
{label: 'Last_Year',  id: 'Last_Year',  type: 'number'},
{label: 'This_Year',  id: 'This_Year',  type: 'number'}],*/
`
I get the following error:
`Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string×`

Comment: Thanks very much that seemed to fix it! I noticed another difference that you didnt mention and that is in my original code I had `google.charts.load('current', {
 
 'packages':['corechart']
});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {`

While you had `google.charts.load('current', {
 callback: drawChart,
 packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {` This seemed to be something as well. why do you have the callback: in Charts.load,

Comment: it supposed to do the same thing but i find placing in the load statement works better, and one less line of code...